# When I include this adminAuth code in node-red settings.js , I get the following error. When I comment it out, it's fine, what's wrong?

Tags: docker, node-red, okta

The entire settings file is the default settings file produced by node-red with the addition of

```
//COMMENT TEST HERE 
    adminAuth: require("./node_modules/node-red-contrib-okta/user-authentication")({
        oktaAPIToken: process.env.OKTA_TOKEN,
        oktaAPIUrl:  process.env.OKTA_URL,               //Okta API url
        groups: [
            {
                groupID: process.env.OKTA_GROUP_ID,    //okta group DD
                permissions: '*'
            }
        ]
    }),
```

When I include this code, I get this error

```
docker-node-red-web-1  | 2022-06-07T20:24:24: PM2 log: App [node-red:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
docker-node-red-web-1  | 2022-06-07T20:24:24: PM2 log: App [node-red:0] starting in -fork mode-
docker-node-red-web-1  | 2022-06-07T20:24:24: PM2 log: App [node-red:0] online
```

when I do not include it, everything works smoothly, what is going wrong?

I can include the authentication code if it helps anyone responding, but I doubt it's really the route of the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Actually Why are you using pm2 in the container? Extend the official Node-RED container, running pm2 in the container just adds a LOT of unneeded complexity

Comment: @hardillb my boss wants me to use pm2 IDK why ='(

Comment: Tell your boss they are wrong

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information in the question to answer this.

The `settings.js` needs to be a properly formatted JavaScript source file. The easiest way to test this is to manually load the settings file in nodejs.

Assuming you have a local directory mounted as `/data` which contains the `settings.js` file, do the following

- cd in to the volume directory
- export all the required environment variables
- run `node`
- type `require('./settings.js')` and press enter

This should give you a exact error message for what is wrong with your `settings.js` file

Comment: So I created a copy of the settings.js file in another directory, and it seems to work. However it still doesn't work in my original node-red file that's using the setttings.js file.

Comment: Why a different directory? It needs to be the same so the paths match. This implies there is something missing in the container or the volumes `node_modules` dir

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being the location of certain directories!

A Little bit hard to explain over text, but there had to be some stuff shuffled around.